# django days-of-week representation in model

Tags: django, django-models, model, days

I have this "Jobs Server" model that i'm building.  I want to include a field that will save which days of the week this job will run on.  Ultimately in the UI, i would like the user to be able to have a series of check boxes(one for each day) that they can select.  What would be the best way to represent this "days-of-week" data in my mode?

```
class Job(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=32, unique=True)
    package = models.ForeignKey(Package)
    binary = models.ForeignKey(Binary)
    host = models.ForeignKey(Host)
    colo = models.ForeignKey(Location)
    group = models.ForeignKey(Group)
    type = models.ForeignKey(Type)
    start = models.TimeField()
    end = models.TimeField()
    days = ?
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want a checkbox for each one, then the easiest thing to do is to create BooleanFields for each of them. If you want to store it as a more complex value (eg. comma separated list or something), create your own widget and play with javascript, then you could go that route.

Answer (score 26):

You may want to create DayOfTheWeek field type, which you can improve in various ways.

This will translate automatically into the local language using the multilingual tools.

```
#myFields.py
from django.utils.translation import gettext as _

DAY_OF_THE_WEEK = {
    '1': _(u'Monday'),
    '2': _(u'Tuesday'),
    '3': _(u'Wednesday'),
    '4': _(u'Thursday'),
    '5': _(u'Friday'),
    '6': _(u'Saturday'), 
    '7': _(u'Sunday'),
}

class DayOfTheWeekField(models.CharField):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        kwargs['choices'] = tuple(sorted(DAY_OF_THE_WEEK.items()))
        kwargs['max_length'] = 1 
        super(DayOfTheWeekField,self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

#models.py
import myFields
(..)
    dayOfTheWeek = myFields.DayOfTheWeekField()
(..)
```

Comment: I see there are down-voters, I am quite curious to see why this do not answers the question in a efficient way.

Comment: probably because of the fact that you're importing `SmallIntegerField` yet extending a `models.CharField`.

Comment: I assume going this route would mean there would be nothing additional with javascript? I am working with a dropdown of days of the week and I need it to be sorted by the day of the week as I am rendering the user's data

Comment: @abhivemp Indeed, no javascript is required. Two files are impacted.

Comment: @MUYBelgium Do you know if it's possible to render the label of the day of the week (for instance, 'Monday') instead of '1' on the jinja template? If so, how would I go about it?

Comment: @abhivemp Last time I checked, nothing has to be done : the default widget used by the field `DayOfTheWeekField` did not display a number but a list of translated name of the day of the week.  Only, the value of the option was a number (or a string with only one char), in the HTML code.  May be you should look something simpler...  `disabled='disabled'`? `something.choices[value]`? May be add a other function to the field, after `def __init__`?

Comment: @abhivemp  Possibly, just the stringification of the field?

Comment: Doesn't allow selecting multiple days of the week though (OP request: day**s**).

Answer (score 23):

Something like this would work.

```
#models.py
DAYS_OF_WEEK = (
    (0, 'Monday'),
    (1, 'Tuesday'),
    (2, 'Wednesday'),
    (3, 'Thursday'),
    (4, 'Friday'),
    (5, 'Saturday'),
    (6, 'Sunday'),
)

days = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=DAYS_OF_WEEK

#forms.py
widgets = { 'days': forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple }
```

Or to save multiple days

```
#models.py
class Days(models.Model):
    day = models.CharField(max_length=8)

days = models.ManyToManyField(Days)

#forms.py
widgets = { 'days': forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple }
```

Comment: I removed my comments. For some reason there's a bug with the page and your widget part keeps disappearing.

Comment: Ah, anyway I gave you a +1. Good answer.

Comment: This only lets me set and store one day of the week.  I need it to accommodate multiple days.  :-(

Comment: In this case create a Days model, and do a M2M field to it

Comment: Or you could try using models.MultipleChoiceField instead of a CharField. Like here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/746173/form-with-checkboxselectmultiple-doesnt-validate

Comment: Best answer if you don't want to go into creating new Field types or widget types.

Comment: In the first part of the code, should it not be an integer field if its all numbers?

Comment: This is not working

Comment: Should the `days` field not be an IntegerField?

Answer (score 0):

Just implemented [django-weekday-field](https://pypi.org/project/django-weekday-field/). Works great!
Hopefully this helps other people who stumble upon this question

EDIT: updated link to pypi since the bitbucket repo was deleted.

It hasn't been updated since 2014 but looking at the code is a great way to get started on answering this question

Comment: 404 when following that link

Comment: Bitbucket link gets an 404, the pypi package hasnt been updated since 2014

Comment: This doesn't work either

Comment: @NobinPegasus That's a pretty useless comment, at least say why it doesn't work. And if you actually read my comment and look at the repo, you'll see it hasn't been updated since 2014.... so yea of course it probably no longer works