# Django - Days of the week (int) isn't rendering a string

Tags: django, django-models

I have a model in my app that stores the a single day of the week as:

```
DAYS = (
        (0, 'Monday'),
        (1, 'Tuesday'),
        (2, 'Wednesday'),
        (3, 'Thursday'),
        (4, 'Friday')
    )

day = models.IntegerField(validators=[MaxValueValidator(4), MinValueValidator(0)], blank=True, choices = DAYS)
```

According to the [Django Documentation,](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/fields/#choices):

> The first element in each tuple is the actual value to be set on the model, and the second element is the human-readable name

However, that doesn't seem to be the case for me. For instance, in this template here in the same app, when I have something like:

```
{{q.day}}
```

This gives me: `1` instead of `Tuesday`.
I tried some suggestions from SO, including [creating your own model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5966629/django-days-of-week-representation-in-model), and even considered passing custom functions through Jinja2, though I feel this to be unnecessarily complex. What would be the best way to go about this. Do I not understand the functionality of this clearly?

Note: I want to store the day to be int because my app is running some complex algorithms and I want to just convert it for display purposes.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
{{ q.get_day_display }}
```

(without parenthesis in the template)

https://docs.djangoproject.com/fr/3.1/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.get_FOO_display

Answer (score 1):

When you have a choice in you model field you must use {{object.get_attribut_display}} not {{object.attribut}}.
Don't forget to read documentation carefully.